# Symfony form price field - custom assert with message

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

By default the message: *This value is not valid.* is not sufficient. I am in the process of adding @Assert to each property in my entities for more specific validation.

I am displaying errors globally at the top of the form - not individually - in case it matters in the context of this discussion.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", nullable=false, precision=10, scale=2)
 * @Assert\Type(message="list price must be a numeric value", type="decimal")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="list price cannot be empty")
 * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(message="list price must be no less than zero", value = 0)
 */

private $listPrice;
```

This is what I have thus far but the form still invalidates when I enter a value "D44.33"

How do I override the default "type" validator? Note the other validators like **GreaterThanOrEqual** works as expected - but for the life of me I cannot get the "type" to work???

Comment: D44.33 is not a decimal value though.  If you want a format where decimal starts with the letter `D` you should write your own custom validation constraint.

Comment: That's the point...I want validation fail and say why it failed

Comment: But I get the generic message which means nothing...doesn't even include the field name that failed...which in the case of globally displayed errors is useless :)

Comment: You're getting the error somewhere else in your form then, because the default for an incorrect type is `This value should be of type {{ type }}.`

Comment: I thought was maybe the case but when I investigated the error I am sure (not at work to confirm) it said the field in question.. any debugging suggestions?

Comment: It could be from a Choice field, or perhaps the wrong form type altogether.  Do you have `error_bubbling` on for all of your fields?  You might want to turn that off and check the errors on each individual field.

Comment: I have it on for the specified field only

Comment: Right but there could be other things failing even without custom assertions

Comment: I can't say for 100% certain but everything posted fine until I dropped the D into the price then it failed but with generic message

Comment: OK so it's a data transformation error (which I assume happens before assertion):

Unable to reverse value for property path "listPrice": Number parsing failed: U_PARSE_ERROR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103980/discussion-between-jason-roman-and-alex-barylski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jason Roman - thanks again for your help

The issue I was facing was solved by using *"invalid_message"* like so:

```
->add('listPrice', null, ['error_bubbling' => true, 'invalid_message' => '{{ value }} is not a valid list price'])
```

Comment: Glad you got it all straightened out!  You should still change the `Type` assertion away from `decimal` too :)

Comment: I dropped it completely - doesn't seem to even get called due to the lower level default type validation???

Answer (score 1):

The type `decimal` is not a valid type in Symfony, so it's probably looking for a custom `decimal` type and trying to transform the data and failing (which would coincide with the type of error messages you are getting).

The list of allowable types is here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Type.html#reference-constraint-type-type

Try using this instead:

```
@Assert\Type(type="float", message="List price must be a numeric value")
```